# Writing to HTML5 localStorage from python/Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, local-storage

I know I need to use a JavaScript API in python to write to html5 localStorage, so I am looking for the most straightforward way of doing this.

My requirement is to share what gets written to localStorage by a Flask REST API with an ExtJS Web UI.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All you need to do is add a

```
<script></script>
```

tag into your html file between which you can use the following code. Store an item in local storage with:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'tom');
```

Retrieve it back with

```
var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
```

Comment: Sweet! That is about as straightforward as it gets.

Comment: How can I now access the item 'name' from flask?