# To save javascript variable into a file

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a script which captures the index values of the check boxes which are checked from a data table in html.I need to save the index values which are stored in a array "indexes" in a text file.So that,thereafter I can use the text file as an input to Flask or any other python code.

```
$('#match').on("click", function() {
//get tr elements of checked inputs
var trs = $("input:checked").closest("tr");
//make an array containing the indexes of these tr elements
var indexes = $.map(trs, function(tr) { return $(tr).index(); });
alert(indexes);
});
```

Comment: Provide your html code .

Comment: We just need a statement in place of alert(indexes) so that instead of giving alerts of values, it saves the values in a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving a data from html form to text file with jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398074/saving-a-data-from-html-form-to-text-file-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: you can send the indexes to your flask with an API call

Comment: You will need to put more context in your question following the guideline.... https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/

In this question specificity you will need to let us know: the sample of your html table,  the result you are expecting and the error you got so far.

Comment: @NMathar: Can you please advice further? I would be using Flask app route for submitting.

Comment: javascript doesn't offer direct access to the client filesystem. the user would have to chose the file where to save the data.

Comment: i am not familiar with cookies or localstorage. but you can look into this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638970/writing-to-html5-localstorage-from-python-flask-app

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama: Following is the HTML:                                                         <button id="match" class="button button1" type="submit" style="border: 7pt solid green; padding:5px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer; background-color: #e0ffe0;">Match</button> and I am creating checkbox for the table using
$("#my_fo_id>tbody>tr").prepend("<input type='checkbox'  id='check_fo' class='checkBoxClass_fo' style='margin-top: 7pt;' name='fo_box'/>");

Comment: Can you please edit your code and put the snippet in proper way ? @user8682462

Comment: <button id="match" class="button button1" type="submit" style="border: 7pt solid green; padding:5px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer; background-color: #e0ffe0;">Match</button>                       $("#my_fo_id>tbody>tr").prepend("<input type='checkbox' id='check_fo' class='checkBoxClass_fo' style='margin-top: 7pt;' name='fo_box'/>");

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with a third party FileSaver.js library. Now just use saveAs()

```
var blob = new Blob([indexes], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
        saveAs(blob, "yourfile.txt");
```

FileSaver.js: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Refference: https://www.websparrow.org/web/how-to-create-and-save-text-file-in-javascript